# How to set ephemeral-storage in Spark with Kubernetes

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

While running a spark job with a Kubernetes cluster, we get the following error:

```
2018-11-30 14:00:47 INFO  DAGScheduler:54 - Resubmitted ShuffleMapTask(1, 58), so marking it as still running.
2018-11-30 14:00:47 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 310.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 311, 10.233.71.29, executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: 
The executor with id 3 exited with exit code -1.
The API gave the following brief reason: Evicted
The API gave the following message: The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container executor was using 515228Ki, which exceeds its request of 0. 
The API gave the following container statuses:
```

How to configure the job so we can increase the ephemeral storage size of each container ?

We use spark 2.4.0 and Kubernetes 1.12.1

The spark submit option is as follow

```
--conf spark.local.dir=/mnt/tmp \
--conf spark.executor.instances=4 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=8 \
--conf spark.executor.memory=100g \
--conf spark.driver.memory=4g \
--conf spark.driver.cores=1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.memoryOverheadFactor=0.1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=spark:2.4.0 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=visionlab \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.myvolume.options.claimName=pvc \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.myvolume.mount.path=/mnt/ \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.myvolume.mount.readOnly=false \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.myvolume.options.claimName=pvc \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.myvolume.mount.path=/mnt/ \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.myvolume.mount.readOnly=false
```

Comment: Can you provide .yaml files for the deployments? API informed that `node was low on resource`, have you tried attaching more space?

Comment: the problem is that the executor pods create an emptyDir in the root `/var/data/spark-1b1495d5-ad6d-4a56-92cd-b10eb81e28fe` to store computation results. The root of our nodes does have enough space and we need to set the `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` to another location but we can't figure out how to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem but I was able to upgrade to Spark 3.x where you can provide a [Pod Template](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/running-on-kubernetes.html#pod-template).

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.podTemplateFile=my_pod_template.yml
```

in which you can set the ephemeral storage request

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: myimage:latest
    resources:
      requests:
        ephemeral-storage: "50Gi"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your spark job do not have enough storage to store temporary cache data

First you need to inspect your pod deployment, to identify the volume name that will be used for mounting such as `spark-local-dir-1`
Then dive into your spark executor pod, print out `$SPARK_LOCAL_DIR` to identify location of current temporary spark data location, modify the path with `"spark.local.dir": "/tmp/spark-temp/"` (to change the `$SPARK_LOCAL_DIR`) in your config, and finally mount your directory with existing pvc claim (notice give large storage e.g. `100GB`). The below code is spark config when submit job on kubernetes.

```
"spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.claimName": "spark-temp-local",
"spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.path": "/tmp/spark-temp",
"spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.readOnly": "false",

"spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.options.claimName": "spark-temp-local",
"spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.path": "/tmp/spark-temp",
"spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-local-dir-1.mount.readOnly": "false",
"spark.local.dir": "/tmp/spark-temp/"
```

Comment: I was using PVC backed by NAS and setup `"spark.local.dir": "/mnt/spark-temp/"`. It gives an illusion that it's writing on NAS but actually it's not. Path was getting created but writing still happens on ephemeral storage.

Hence, spark setting must be applied in order to use the PVC.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rico says, there's no way to set ephemeral storage limits via driver configurations as of spark 2.4.3. Instead, you can set ephemeral storage limits for all new pods in your namespace using a [LimitRange](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: ephemeral-storage-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      ephemeral-storage: 8Gi
    defaultRequest:
      ephemeral-storage: 1Gi
    type: Container
```

This applies the defaults to executors created in the LimitRange's namespace:

```sh
$ kubectl get pod spark-kub-1558558662866-exec-67 -o json | jq '.spec.containers[0].resources.requests."ephemeral-storage"'
"1Gi"
```

It's a little heavy-handed because it applies the default to all containers in your namespace, but it may be a solution if your workload is uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your job might be requesting `0` in the pod on the ephemeral-storage. If you look at the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable) you'll see that the ephemeral storage is part of the root disk on your nodes. So you can try specifying a [`hostPath`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#using-kubernetes-volumes) mount instead.

My guess is that is something is happening with the PVC and the container is using an ephemeral-volume, or it could be that you need both a hostPath and a PVC (for `/mnt/tmp`) if you are specifying volumes. I would check:

```
$ kubectl describe pvc
$ kubectl describe pv
```

There is no option in the [Spark Driver](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#running-spark-on-kubernetes) to issue a Kubernetes [`Request`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#local-ephemeral-storage) for limits on ephemeral storage as of this writing.

Comment: I tried to map /tmp of each executor to a local volume on nodes with hostPath but it seems to have no effects.

Comment: Do you think this could happen if I don't have enough space on my PCV ?

Comment: So far, what I understand is that SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS is attached to an emptyDir and need an ephemeral storage. Is there a way to change this behavior and attach it to an hostPath ?